# css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, apache

I am using netbeans 8.2 ide, Apache 2.4 with php7.

I have downloaded Bootstrap and am trying to link it into index.php i haven't far. When I test the example page on localhost I the error "css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”"

Things I have tried (restarting the erver between each):

- "AddType text/css .css" in my httpd.conf file and also in vhost
- ensured php strict_mode is off (saw it in a post)
- checked mime.types for the type (which is there) text/css - css
- changed default_mimetype = "text/html" to default_mimetype = "" in the php.ini file

UPDATE

I did a bit more research turns out PHP will parse .css as html for whatever reason and change its mime type ( not exactly sure how that all works but seems to be the case). So I renamed the .css files as .php files and added the code  into each .css file

```
header('Content-type: text/css', true);
```

this did not work, I then added into index.php the following:

```
header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
```

this just prevented the loading of the stylesheets because of lack of mime type at all! even in conjunction with Content-type.

also i have included a capture of the request and response headers to the server[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHvmf.png)

thank you very much for any help this is very frustrating I'm trying to get into some basic web design but I can't even make it past the included Netbeans template. I have a feeling it's something to do with the configuration of PHP7 or Apache 2.4 but i have no idea were to go next

Comment: Did you declare `type="text/css"`
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your/css/file.css">

Comment: You might have done something stupid. Check if the filename extension is .css

Comment: Particularly, aren't you trying to load the bootstrap js component using a <link>.

Comment: Yes yes and yes. I did declare text/css. The style sheet is .css and bootstrap js is loading fine. I'm using the netbeans standard template wich works fine when index is .html but not when I changed it .php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling my self configured Apache server and installed the pre-configured WAMP Apache server which solved my problem so there a configuration problem somewhere not sure what but everything is working great now.

Comment: I am having this same problem right now. On XAMPP. I wonder if there is a solution I can't find. I tried WAMP before and I couldn't even get my app to run.